# SSRS giving error for BackgroundGradientEndColor expression, but I don't have an expression

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I modeled this gauge after a working gauge on another report. (I didn't copy the XML. It is rather basic.) SSRS says:

```
An error occurred during local report processing.
The definition of the report '...' is invalid.
The BackgroundGradientEndColor expression for the 
gauge panel 'RevenueGaugePanel' has a scope parameter 
that is not valid for an aggregate function. The
scope parameter must be set to a string constant 
that is equal to either the name of a containing 
group, the name of a contain data region, or the 
name of a dataset.
```

The gauge's BackgroundGradientEndColor is set to Gray, as you can see in the image. There is no expression. I tried changing to to Orange, but no difference. What is going on?[image: RevenueGaugePanel properties window]

Comment: Try opening the .rdl file in a text editor (it's xml) - it might reveal something.

Answer (score 0):

What if you sort the properties by AZ instead of categorical. Maybe more options will reveal something.